# Primary / Foreign Key example

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to figure out relationships between my tables and the notion of how it all inter-relates is not clear.
Lets say I have a Person table (first name, last name, etc) where the Primary key is social security number.
I also have a Fireman table that has just 2 columns -- date when joined the fire company, and a unique fireman number.  The 3rd column would be a link back to the Person table.
Initially, I made SSN in the Fireman table to be a foreign key linking to SSN in the Person table.  But doesnt it imply that every time I create a new Fireman, I can re-use the same SSN over and over?  The foreign key constraint would not be violated -- so its "all good" -- but its not what I want.  Does it make sense? I dont want to allow for different unique Fireman numbers all sharing the same SSN number.  So how do I set this up -- whats Primary, whats foreign, whats one to one and whats one to many.

Answer (score 0):

A key can be primary and foreign all at the same time in a one-to-one relationship.

You can scrap your primary key from the `Fireman` table, and just use `SSN` as the unique key. Since it's one-to-one, there's no need for a separate identifier.

Alternatively, you could create a unique index on the column SSN in your fireman table. That would prevent duplicate entry.

Note that data validation, relationships and indexes are all separate things. You can use indexes and relationships to validate data, but you can also use different concepts, like constraints.